# What is the correct MTU setting for the gnuradio UDP Source block for a payload size less than the default 1472?

Tags: udp, gnuradio, mtu

The gnuradio UDP Source block has a default Payload Size of 1472. The documentation indicates

"payload_size : UDP payload size by default set to 1472 = (1500 MTU - (8 byte UDP header) - (20 byte IP header))"

My C client program sends packets of 16 bytes to the gnuradio udp source once every second.

Should I set the MTU value to 16?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, the `Payload Size` refers to the maximum packet size that can be handled by the block. However, the block then handles your 16 byte as a stream, so if you like to keep this packet form additional steps are required.

Comment: I do not know the significance of handling my 16 bytes as a stream versus a packet. What additional steps are required?

Comment: Depends on your application. If the 16-bytes group is significant for you, you may group them in a vector, or declare the start of each packet with a tag. If it it does not matter, let them as a stream.